# overstayed schengen visa

Tags: schengen, overstaying, visa-free-entry

Citizens of my country don't need a schengen zone visa to enter. however we're allowed to stay 90 days on a 180 period. i travelled for three month and didn't count properly and stayed 91 days. when I left the schengen zone i wasn't told anything. i haven't received any notice either.

how can i know if i'm facing any consequence? i'm planning on travelong again for three months, obviously respecting the three month period that i have to wait. is there any chance they won't let me in the schengen zone?

Comment: It is possible that they missed it on exit and that they will miss it on the next entry. We cannot know that. Did you get stamps on entry and exit?

Comment: I second o.m. here. If noone said anything when you left the Schengen area, chances are high that noone noticed. I assume that your passport was stamped properly on entry and exit, in which case it is possible that the overstay will be noticed when you try to enter the next time.

Comment: @Traveller Are you saying that the penalties for overstaying on visa-free entry are the same as the penalties for overstaying on a visa?

Comment: @DavidRicherby the penalties are set in national law, so it would be somewhat labor intensive to establish that they are the same in every Schengen country's laws.  But I suppose it's likely that they are.

Comment: To be more precise than "three months I have to wait": you have to be outside the Schengen area for at least 90 days before you can reenter.  If your stay had been less than 90 days, the conditions on your reentry would be somewhat different.

Comment: A (now deleted) answer suggested that you'd be found out through database tracking of entries and exits.  There is no Schengen-wide system for this (not yet, at least), but some individual countries do have such systems.  The country or countries you traveled through before probably doesn't or don't, otherwise they probably would have noticed the overstay when you left.  But you might want to enter and leave through a different country next time to reduce the chance of problems at the border.